# CSS Reverse Image Height by Viewport

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make an image zoom and adjust height to a bigger size when viewport gets smaller/ minimized instead of the other way around. For instance when i make a window smaller the image should get longer on the page.

```
background-image: url(../images/bgimg-aboutme.jpg);
/* Settings */                                  /* Settings */
height: 50vmin;
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Please help i would really like to know how this is done either from js or other languages. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps achieve this using only css, however I would prefer to use css + js in this case, as it will give you bit of fine grained control. You can set the desired maxImageWidth, maxClientWidth, maxClientHeight and minClientWidth without causing image to jump within a floating div. I **throttled** the `resize` event as well:

```
!function(){
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0],
      maxImageWidth  = 4000,
      maxClientWidth = 2000,
      maxClientHeight  = 1000,
      minClientWidth = 200;

  window.addEventListener("resize",function(e){
    if(img._busy){return}
    img._busy = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      adjust();
      img._busy = false;
    })
  });

  function adjust(){
    if(!img._ratio){
      var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      img._ratio = rect.height/rect.width;
    }
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        currentImageWidth = maxImageWidth * (1 - Math.max(0,Math.min(1,(w - minClientWidth)/(maxClientWidth - minClientWidth))));
    img.style.width = currentImageWidth + "px";
    var currentImageHeight = currentImageWidth * img._ratio;
    img.style.marginTop = -Math.max(0,(currentImageHeight - maxClientHeight)/2) + "px";
  };


  adjust();
}();
```

Also do not forget to add `min-height:100%` and `min-width:100%` on the img.
See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/2bshrue9/)**
Tested on evergreen browsers + ie11.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This should serve as a rudimentary example of how to achieve what you're looking for in JavaScript. We're making a couple of basic assumptions to calculate the height of the image: For each percentage of the viewport height the wrapper shrinks, the image will increase by a percentage. So, if the wrapper is 99vh, the image will be 101vh.

This example illustrates how you can achieve what you're looking for, you should be able do it from here.

```js
// get the image
let imgObj = document.getElementById('image')
// get the wrapper
let wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('image-wrapper')[0]
// get the viewport height
let viewPort = window.innerHeight
// get the wrapper height
let wrapperHeight = wrapper.clientHeight
// calculate the image size based on the size of the wrapper as a percentage of the viewport.
// E.g. If the wrapper is 40% of the viewport, the image will be 160% of the viewport
let imageHeight = 200 - ((wrapperHeight / viewPort) * 100)
// set the new image height
imgObj.style.height = imageHeight + 'vh'
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {}
.image-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.image-content {
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" id="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```